# how to stop Checkbox from getting unchecked when page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, web-applications

So I'm creating a to-do list, and I'm saving the task to the localStorage, when I refresh the page the task stay but the checkbox gets unchecked how could I stop the checkbox from getting unchecked when I refresh the page
note: I'm creating the checkbox via js so when I add a task it creates the checkbox dynamically.

```
/* arry that holds tasks */
let tasks = [];

/* create a todo object */
const addTask = (text) => {
    const todoTask = {
        text,
        checked: false,
        id: Date.now(),
    }
    tasks.push(todoTask);
    renderTodo(todoTask);
};
 
const formT = document.querySelector(`[data-new-todo-form]`)
const inputT = document.querySelector(`[data-new-todo-input]`)
const todoList = document.getElementById('todo-list');

formT.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    let text = inputT.value.trim();
    if(text !== '') {
       addTask(text);
       inputT.value = '';
       inputT.focus();

    } 
 
})

const renderTodo = (todoTask)=> {

    localStorage.setItem('tasksRef', JSON.stringify(tasks));


    const item = document.querySelector(`[data-key='${todoTask.id}']`);

    if (todoTask.deleted) {
        // remove the item from the DOM
        item.remove();
        return
      }

    const isChecked = todoTask.checked ? 'done': '';

    const node = document.createElement('li')
    node.setAttribute('class', `todo-item ${isChecked}`);
    node.setAttribute('data-key', todoTask.id);
    node.innerHTML = `
    
    <input class="js-tick save-cb-state" id="${todoTask.id}" type="checkbox"/>
    <span>${todoTask.text}</span>
    <img class="delete" width="15px" height='15px' src="/images/icon-cross.svg" alt="cross">`
    ;
    todoList.append(node);

    if (item) {
        node.replaceWith(item)
    } else {
        todoList.append(node)
    }
}

todoList.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('js-tick')) {
        const itemKey = e.target.parentElement.dataset.key;
        toggleDone(itemKey);
    }

    if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
        const itemKey = e.target.parentElement.dataset.key;
        deleteTodo(itemKey);
      }
    
});

const toggleDone = (key) => {
    
    const index = tasks.findIndex(task=> task.id === Number(key));

    tasks[index].checked = !tasks[index].checked;
    renderTodo(tasks[index]);
}
const deleteTodo = (key) => {
    const index = tasks.findIndex(item => item.id === Number(key));

    const todoTask = {
        deleted: true,
        ...tasks[index]
      };
      tasks = tasks.filter(item => item.id !== Number(key));
  renderTodo(todoTask);
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const ref = localStorage.getItem('tasksRef');
    if (ref) {
      tasks = JSON.parse(ref);
      tasks.forEach(task => {
        renderTodo(task);
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you add checkbox to DOM you should set Checked attribute for that.
change renderTodo with this code:

```
node.innerHTML = `   
<input class="js-tick save-cb-state" id="${todoTask.id}" type="checkbox" ${isChecked ? "checked" : ""}/>
<span>${todoTask.text}</span>
<img class="delete" width="15px" height='15px' src="/images/icon-cross.svg" alt="cross">`
;
```

if you putted your html code I could create live Demo, I think this change will be fixed  your problem